# How do you wait to initialize an array until you know the length?

Tags: java, arrays, global

I want to create a series of 6 parallel arrays that are global variables to store file input, but I won't know how long they are meant to be until I've processed a part of the input. Is there a way to delay the initialization of an array until I've processed the length of the array?

Comment: `ArrayList` should be the easier choice if you need to store some of the input before you know the final size.

Comment: For some reason we aren't allowed to use array lists, nor have we been officially taught them. Maybe they're considered too easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to initialize a variable then give it a value later.

```
int[] myArray;
//... Do stuff.
myArray = new int[theLengthIWant];
```

Comment: Thanks, so once I extract the desired length I can give it a length in an if statement and it will still be available to be passed onto the other methods?

Comment: @Spork Yes, as long as you can keep it as a variable.